# Currency Symbols to Numerical Encoding

Tags: php

I m having many currency symbols. i want to convert them to numerical unicode like £ to &#163; as I need to extract this number 163 and use it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people already implemented ["uniord"](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ord.php#77905) ;)

```
function uniord($c) {
    $h = ord($c{0});
    if ($h <= 0x7F) {
        return $h;
    } else if ($h < 0xC2) {
        return false;
    } else if ($h <= 0xDF) {
        return ($h & 0x1F) << 6 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F);
    } else if ($h <= 0xEF) {
        return ($h & 0x0F) << 12 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F) << 6
                                 | (ord($c{2}) & 0x3F);
    } else if ($h <= 0xF4) {
        return ($h & 0x0F) << 18 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F) << 12
                                 | (ord($c{2}) & 0x3F) << 6
                                 | (ord($c{3}) & 0x3F);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I guess you're using ISO-8859-1(5), in this case Aleks G' solution should work

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with simply using `ord` function?

```
$symbol = "£";
$code = ord($symbol);  //should return 163
```

Comment: It depends on the default charset ^^ (I get 194 after testing)

Answer (score 0):

URL Encode gives you everything in hexidecimal format, but when converted to an int, it gives you the UTF-8 char code without the need for workarounds.

```
<?php echo hexdec(substr(urlencode('£'), -2, 2)); ?>
```

---

**EDIT**
Perhaps [`mb_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) could help with your [encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) issues.

Comment: It is giving me &pound; not in numerical form.

Comment: There might be a way around that. Gimme a sec.

Comment: It seems like URL encode wants to misbehave and add some random letter before your pound symbol. Fixing...

Comment: It's probably more trouble than it's worth, but it seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

In case you only want to replace some characters in a string, use the replac function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

EDIT: For this you need to know the codes beforehand, but you can find most here: http://w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

And dollar, that isn't in that list, is &# 36;